Use a `Protocol` instead of concrete @MainActor class produces an error
Could anyone please clarify how the concurrency checking works in my case? I have an actor that calls the foo method of a @MainActor class:
actor MyActor {
    let property: MainActorClass

    init(property: MainActorClass) {
        self.property = property
    }

    func doSomething() async {
        await property.foo()
    }
}

@MainActor
class MainActorClass {
    func foo() async {
        print("foo")
    }
}

It compiles with Swift 6, but when I'm trying to abstract my MainActorClass with MainActorProtocol:
actor MyActor {
    let property: MainActorProtocol

    init(property: MainActorProtocol) {
        self.property = property
    }

    func doSomething() async {
        await property.foo()
    }
}

@MainActor
protocol MainActorProtocol {
    func foo() async
}

class MainActorClass: MainActorProtocol {
    func foo() async {
        print("foo")
    }
}

I am getting an error:
Sending 'self.property' risks causing data races
What's the difference between these two approaches and how can I abstract my MainActorClass with a Protocol?
I tried to add Sendable to a Protocol but it looks a little bit cumbersome to add Sendable to almost every protocol in a project.

A main-actor isolated protocol is not Sendable, but a main actor isolated class is. I can’t explain why though.

@Sweeper does it mean that we should mark every protocol that passed as a dependency to an Actor as Sendable? Sounds like a lot of changes for big projects!

Region-based isolation in Xcode 16 will address a great number of these. But in the most general terms, yes. That said, if this really is the kind of abstraction you're doing with the protocol (i.e. the protocol and the actor have identical interfaces), you're probably overusing protocols. Protocols are not abstract classes. If every type you have also has a protocol, then yeah, it's likely going to be a headache, but that's generally a bad design in the first place.

IMHO, marking the relevant protocols as Sendable is not an unreasonable request in exchange for the compiler being able to warn us of data races. It would be unreasonable to ask the compiler to provide us those assurances in the absence of this conformance requirement. Often, the adding Sendable to the protocol definition is trivial in comparison to the work of actually making the conforming types actually satisfy the requirement…
